# What is shortcut key to change tab in Spring tool suite?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

Assuming that many tab opening while doing the coding..

What is shortcut key to go to another tab?

In visual Studio shortcutkey (ctrl + tab) is available to change tab but not sure spring tool suite providing or not.

Thanks

Comment: ctrl + f6 try this

Comment: Since STS is eclipse based, I suppose this should be a duplicate

Comment: @AliDehghani This is about eclipse.. I ask about Spring tool suite

Comment: @Parth solanki: Thank you for providing answer.

Comment: The Spring Tool Suite is an **Eclipse-based** development ...https://spring.io/tools/sts

Comment: @AliDehghani Thats what I am saying that whoever new in STS they search only for STS not eclipse.. So there is gap in the existing question.

Comment: @AliDehghani  Thank you for providing info. Kindly remove request for duplication.